# grep - mark the same digits in the line bash

Tags: grep

I want to mark the same digits, which can repeat 3 times.
My command:

```
grep -E '[[:digit:]]{2,3}' file
```

mark every digits, but I want to one the same digit.

Input:

```
11111 222 33
2223345678912345678901234
5
```

Output:

```
11111 222 33
2223345678912345678901234
5
```

I want to:

```
11111 222 33<-mark 222
2223345678912345678901234<-mark 222
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Where is the difference between input and output?

Comment: There is no difference, because of my grep command.

Comment: Replcae output by your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that you can grep a file for 3 consecutive numbers using the following command:

```
grep "\([0-9]\)\\1\\1" chatlog.txt
```

This marks all lines that have 3 consecutive identical numbers. the `\\1` matches the character that was matched in the first group, in this case a number.

So to match 4 identical numbers you would want:

```
grep "\([0-9]\)\\1\\1\\1" chatlog.txt
```

You can define this in a more flexible way:

```
grep "\([0-9]\)\(\\1\)\{2,3\}"
```

The above statement will match series of 3 or 4 consecutive identical numbers. Mind that the first group matches the first digit. Afterwards you match that group either two or three more times.

So given the input:

```
one: 1
two: 11
three: 111
four: 1111
```

The following command:

```
grep -r "\([0-9]\)\(\\1\)\{2,3\}" test.txt
```

Returns:

```
three: 111
four: 1111
```

Comment: Ok that's very good. But I want to make a interval, I mean that digits can be in the line one, two or three times in the line.

Comment: Does the above edit answer your question?